# Pinch gesture not applied to UILabel but applied to UIView

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I am just trying out pinch gesture on UILabel but it's not working. When I applied the same to UIView it works.

Below is my code:

in viewDidLoad

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchLabel = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchLabel:)];
[pinchLabel setDelegate:self];
[_lblDouble addGestureRecognizer:pinchLabel];

-(void)pinchLabel:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
NSLog(@"jhhj"); // method never gets called. I have a breakpoint here.
}
```

Why is it so? Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: have you enable `_lblDouble.userInteractionEnabled = yes` ?

Comment: Is the delegate called? Are you setting the frame of the label or a scale transform?

Comment: @ChinttuRoxeNRamani Thanks mate. I had not set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of label to `YES`. It works now. Please answer the question so that I can accept it.

Comment: @ChinttuRoxenNRamani what does this have to do with my question? I wanted you to clarify in your question and I am well aware of userInteractionEnabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should add below code. otherwise all code looks ok.

```
_lblDouble.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```